# How to use combine to publish the currentTime property of AVAudioPlayer?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

Im writing a simple music player and I need continuous updates of the current time of the audio from AVAudioPlayer to smoothly and continuously update my slider in SwiftUI.
I have a class (view model) but I don't know how to publish the currentTime property from there to my view. Here is the code I currently have.

```
class AudioPlaybackManager: NSObject, ObservableObject {        
    @Published var duration = 0.0
    
    var timer = Timer.publish(every: 1.0, tolerance: 0.5, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    
    @Published var sliderValue = 0.0 
    
    var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?

    private func changeSliderValue() {
        audioPlayer?.currentTime = sliderValue
    }
    
}

//My view
struct Scrubber: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var audioPlaybackManager: AudioPlaybackManager
        
    var body: some View {
        Slider(value: $audioPlaybackManager.sliderValue, in: 0...audioPlaybackManager.duration) { _ in
            audioPlaybackManager.audioPlayer?.currentTime = audioPlaybackManager.sliderValue
        }
        .onReceive(audioPlaybackManager.timer) { _ in
            withAnimation(.easeInOut) {
                if audioPlaybackManager.isPlaying {
                    audioPlaybackManager.sliderValue = audioPlaybackManager.audioPlayer?.currentTime ?? 0.0
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is using AVAudioPlayerNode an option for you? Otherwise, using the addPeriodTimeObserver @TheLivingForce is what I would use.

Answer (score 3):

You can't directly publish the currentTime property through KVO. For your use case (a continuous time scroller), I'd advise looking at [addPeriodicTimeObserver](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer/1385829-addperiodictimeobserver).

[Here's a combine publisher](https://gist.github.com/kshivang/4c213ec85adf911d30f1305722e7129d) gist for what you seem to be looking for.